# Razorpay signature verification not happening as SHA256 Digest is wrong NodeJS

Tags: node.js, razorpay

I am making an app in which after a successful payment I create a digest which I verify using the suggest way of Razorpay signature verification.

My backend is in NodeJS and here is how I am creating the digest.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

 var generatedSignature = crypto
      .createHmac(
        "SHA256",
        razorpay_order_id + "|" + razorpay_payment_id
      )
      .update(key_secret)
      .digest("hex");  

var isSignatureValid = generatedSignature == payload.razorpay_signature // false
```

Is my way of creating signature wrong?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the following code. Hope this makes a more understandable code.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', RAZORPAY_KEY_SECRET);

hmac.update(razorpayOrderId + "|" + razorpayPaymentId);
let generatedSignature = hmac.digest('hex');

let isSignatureValid = generatedSignature == payload.razorpay_signature;
```

Refer this link for more https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hmac

Comment: to the point answer. It really help a lot. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

2022 Update:

Just checked razorpay documentation:

Suggested approach:

```
const razorpay = require("razorpay");
const isValid = razorpay.validateWebhookSignature(reqBody, signature, mySecret);
```

Documentation Link:
https://razorpay.com/docs/payments/payment-gateway/server-integration/nodejs/#subscribe-to-webhook-events

Comment: isValid would always be null or undefined, since razorpay signature verifications return void. Just wrap them in  TRY_CATCH(exception handling)  because if the signature is not verified it throws an error

Answer (score 1):

You just have to change the createHmac and update like below swapping parameters in them.

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

var generatedSignature = crypto
  .createHmac(
    "SHA256",
    key_secret
  )
  .update(razorpay_order_id + "|" + razorpay_payment_id)
  .digest("hex");  

 var isSignatureValid = generatedSignature == payload.razorpay_signature;
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Going through the official razorpay npm module, found this function that does the job for you. Might as well utilise this.

file name & directory: node_modules/razorpay/dist/utils/razorpay-utils.js, function name: validateWebhookSignature

Takes in 'body' -- hashing sequence,
         'signature' -- razorpay returned signature,
         'key_secret' -- from razorpay dashboard

This uses the same crypto.hmac_256 function as mentioned previously on this thread.

UPDATE:
Tested using this function, returns false ==> signature not matching.

Read on GitHub that the signature won't match using test key. It'll work when using live key.

Will update this thread when I try using production keys.
Cheers!

Comment: Tested this. Returns false ==> hash not matching.

Answer (score 0):

```
const crypto=require('crypto');
const json = JSON.stringify(req.body); // req.body is entire body payload 
const expectedSignature = 
crypto.createHmac('sha256',secretKey).update(json).digest('hex');
// secretKey is configured key provided by us while creating webhook


//--- Or Use razorpay static method 

/*
@params body string (body is req.body data)
@params razorpayHeaderSignature string (x-razorpay-signature of header section 
provided by webhook)
@params secretKey (secretKey is configured key provided by us while creating webhook)
*/

const json = JSON.stringify(req.body); // req.body is entire body payload 
Razorpay.validateWebhookSignature(body, razorpayHeaderSignature, secretKey);
```

*NOTE - IN request body don't use some of the special characters like '/' etc. It causes verification of signature to fail.*

Answer (score 0):

The below solution worked for me

```
     import crypto from 'crypto';

     const signature = req.headers['x-razorpay-signature'];
     const generatedSignature = crypto
      .createHmac('sha256', RAZOR_PAY_WEBHOOK_SECRET)
      .update(JSON.stringify(req.body))
      .digest('hex');

    if (signature === generatedSignature) {
      console.log('request is legit');
    }
    else{
      console.log('Wrong Signature!');
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample valid signature, a sample request body, and the generated signature to your question?